# How are BLAST record scores calculated in biopython

Tags: sequence-alignment, python, phylogenetics, blastp

Can someone explain how the score is calculated for [Bio.Blast.Record.Description](https://biopython.org/docs/latest/api/Bio.Blast.Record.html#Bio.Blast.Record.Description)?  For example, if `Record.Description.num_alignments` is >1, is `Record.Description.score` simply the sum of the alignment scores for the description's hit?  Can alignments overlap?  How does the score of a given alignment deal with the scores of overlapping HSPs in that alignment?

I'm getting the `Blast.Record` object via [NCBIXML.parse()](https://biopython.org/docs/latest/api/Bio.Blast.NCBIXML.html#Bio.Blast.NCBIXML.parse), and would like to rely on the description data as much as possible to remove the need for code that parses the [Record.Alignments](https://biopython.org/docs/latest/api/Bio.Blast.Record.html#Bio.Blast.Record.Alignment) objects, but I'm a nervous including things when I don't know exactly how they were created.

Cheers!
Tim

Answer (score 1):

The results you'd get are the same as with any other NCBI BLAST+ tools, python does not compute it.

Biopython can run a blast query `qblast` on the internet or locally. To make it run locally you need to install blast tools on your machine and biopython will launch it as a subprocess. Here you can find the pertinent information: https://biopython.org/docs/dev/Tutorial/chapter_blast.html#running-blast-locally

Filtering data is as much a burden as it is important. Depending on your question you want to answer. Some people prefer a low e-value. The score is however affected by the length of the sequence since the number of matches is bigger, more details here: https://www.nlm.nih.gov/ncbi/workshops/2023-08_BLAST_evol/blast_score.html